# Python logging, how to write info to 2 separate

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying log to different StringIOs. I would've expected that each logger would write to each StringIO that was instantiated and given to. But that's not working, only the first StringIO stores the logged info.
Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

```
    import logging
    from StringIO import StringIO
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-3s %(levelname)-4s %(message)s')

    log_stream1 = StringIO()
    log1 = logging.getLogger('a')
    log1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler1 = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream1)
    stream_handler1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler1.setFormatter(formatter)
    log1.addHandler(stream_handler1)

    log_stream2 = StringIO()
    log2 = logging.getLogger('b')
    log2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handler2 = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream2)
    stream_handler2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
    log2.addHandler(stream_handler1)

    log1.info('log1')
    log2.info('log2')
```

output:

```
    In [6]: log_stream1.getvalue()
    Out[6]: '2017-06-08 10:05:12,468 a   INFO log1\n2017-06-08 10:05:12,468 b   INFO log2\n'

    In [7]: log_stream2.getvalue()
    Out[7]: ''
```

Comment: change `log2.addHandler(stream_handler1)` to `log2.addHandler(stream_handler2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
log2.addHandler(stream_handler1)
```

To

```
log2.addHandler(stream_handler2)
```

Entire code:

```
import logging
from StringIO import StringIO
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-3s %(levelname)-4s %(message)s')

log_stream1 = StringIO()
log1 = logging.getLogger('a')
log1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler1 = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream1)
stream_handler1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler1.setFormatter(formatter)
log1.addHandler(stream_handler1)

log_stream2 = StringIO()
log2 = logging.getLogger('b')
log2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler2 = logging.StreamHandler(log_stream2)
stream_handler2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
log2.addHandler(stream_handler2)

log1.info('log1')
log2.info('log2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `log2.addHandler(stream_handler1)`.
You should write `log2.addHandler(stream_handler2)`.